# Macro to copy data into More rows with a consecutive monthly date

Tags: excel, vba

I use a macro form where I write an amount that I receive every month X times
[An example of how I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVMXp.png)

How can I make a macro that will continue to fill new rows with the next month, according to the times I registered
This is the code I have now, without adding more lines

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("sheets")
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    With ws
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = ""
        .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
End With
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

(Note: This adds new rows, not at the expense of existing lines)

I will be happy for any help, idea, intention

**editing:**
More clarity what I want

If I write on Form No. 9 and 500$ , then will add 9 lines, with 500$ amount, but with a monthly date rising

I'm not a macro expert

[e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKuwj.png)

Comment: Does this work for one iteration? Your question is not clear. It looks like you are adding a new row of data spanning columns A:D. What is not working about this?

Comment: Are you saying, every time you press `closed` it needs to add that data to the next cell in line?

Comment: I added clarity to the question

Comment: OP, please add a photo of the expected output given the entries you have shown in your userform. This way, nobody wastes time writing a solution that is not what you need :)

Comment: `.Range(.Cells(lRow, 2), .Cells(lRow + Me.TextBox1.Value, 2)) = Me.TextBox1.Value`

Comment: I changed the picture, thanks for the comment

Comment: See me another picture? I think I do not know how to use well, I apologize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to validate the entries. What if the user puts `al;kjfdadsk` into any textbox? You need to make sure the inputs are in line with the expectation.

Limit the inputs like so:

`Me.TextBox1` = `Number`
`Me.TextBox2` = `Date`
`Me.TextBox1` = `Number`

You can also amend this to make sure `Amount` is non-negative. Or maybe there is a max you want to set on `Amount`? Either way, it is worthwhile thinking about the limitations you want to place here and then build them in. I added the 3 limitations above in the code for you.

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Validate entries    
If Not IsNumeric(Me.TextBox1) Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Amount Entry"
ElseIf Not IsDate(Me.TextBox2) Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Date Entry"
ElseIf Not IsNumeric(Me.TextBox3) Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Payment Entry"
End If

'Rest of code goes here and will be ran once the above entries are validated
Dim ws As Worksheet, LRow as Long, i as Integer
Set ws = Worksheets("sheets")

LRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

ws.Range("A" & LRow) = Me.TextBox2
ws.Range(ws.Cells(LRow, 2), ws.Cells(LRow + Me.TextBox1, 2)) = Me.TextBox3

For i = (LRow + 1) To (LRow + Me.TextBox1 - 1)
    ws.Range("A" & i ) = DateAdd("m", 1, ws.Range("A" & i -1)
Next i

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: The power of a full and complete picture <3 Please accent the solution now that your problem is solved :)

Comment: Indeed, in the future I will pay attention to bring an accurate and clear question, greatly appreciates your help, note that there are missing the last brackets in your code

Comment: Will you have time to comment on the previous comment?

Comment: About adding one line too much, adding "-1" `(LRow + Me.TextBox1 - 1, 2)`

Comment: Yes, it works right now, I really appreciate your help